# Java/android - check if string `FileName` contains any file-name-disallowed characters

Tags: java, android, regex, filenames

I am checking if a string `filename` is safe for saving by checking if it has any strange characters with a Regular expression. It is will be a .json file and should also allow spaces in the file name.

```
public static boolean fileNameIsSafe(String nameIncExt) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("regex?").matcher(nameIncExt);
        return m.matches();
    }
```

What would the regular expression be?

Comment: Can we see some example data: correct and incorrect input? Also your regex attempt would be nice.

Comment: Please define "strange characters." I would use that term to refer to my sister's ex-boyfriends.

Comment: John Smith.json that sort of thing. Strange characters are like /\][;'etc that would not be allowed in a file name

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more elegant solution - I'm not a regex expert, but how about this:

`[.]*\w[\w| |.]*`

Breaking it down:

```
[.]*
```

The filename can start with 0 or more '.'s

```
\w
```

Then you need at least one word character, which can be a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _. this prevents file names of '...' or file names that start with a space, or only contain '.'s and spaces.

```
[\w| |.]*
```

The remaining file name can have 0 or more word characters, spaces, and/or '.' I'm assuming you can trim off trailing spaces.

Note in Java you'll need to escape the backslashes, so it would look like this:

```
boolean isSafeFilename = Pattern.matches("[.]*\\w[\\w| |.]*", stringToTest);
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that you've never visited this site: [Regular-Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Anyway, you can match characters within a character class: `[/\]\[;']`

Comment: I can't seem to find what I'm looking for on that site, and what do you mean by a character class?

Comment: `[this text is inside a character class]` and it will match any of the following characters, only once: `acdehilnrstx `

Comment: So how would you use this to remove "/?%*:\"<>/|!@#$^&{}`~[];,'" from file name and return a 'safe' string, or return false in the isSafe().